# Turn off Facebook notification sounds on message requests

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

How do I turn off notification sounds when someone that I never talked with before wants to send me a message?

When my phone makes a sound, I want it to notify me of something that needs my immediate attention.

Message requests are overused for marketing porn accounts and I can ignore those later.

Comment: I have the same problem. Frustratingly it does not seem to be possible to turn off notification for message requests without also turning off notifications for new messages. I have turned off sound notifications from Messenger, but the screen notifications still annoy me.